# Why might the convolution be inappropriate when the task involves incorporating information from very distant locations in the input?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, convolution

When I am reading about convolutional neural networks, I have encountered the following sentence from the [textbook](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/convnets.html)(page 341) that says about the limitation of the usage of the convolution in CNNs.

> When a task involves incorporating information from **very distant
> locations** in the input, then the prior imposed by convolution may be
> inappropriate

My interpretations are

1. when the object is very small, then the convolution may not work
   well.
2. when the object is very large, then the components of the object are far away from each other and hence the convolution may not work well.

Which of the interpretation is correct? If both are wrong, then what is the correct interpretation.

If possible, please provide an example to understand it.

Comment: I think that your second interpretation is correct because the kernel is typically a lot smaller than the input. Maybe [this answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/25850/2444) may provide some intuition.